# Локализация -Как русифицировать страницы MAN в Linux mint?

Tags: локализация, linux-mint, man

Как русифицировать страницы *MAN*  в *Linux mint*?

Comment: Предельно конкретный вопрос же.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, немного неопределённости есть — требуется либо прочитать существующие переведённые страницы, либо сделать перевод самостоятельно. вероятность второго, конечно, близка к нулю, но всё-таки чуть теплится.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: для второго дистрибутив вроде бы не имеет значения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

надеюсь, я правильно понял вопрос, что интересует отображение уже готовых, а не написание новых *man*-страниц.

---

*man*-страницы обычно входят в пакеты с программами.

например, в пакет `gnupg` входят такие файлы с *man*-страницами:

```
$ dpkg -L gnupg | grep 'man.*gz'
/usr/share/man/man1/gpg.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/lspgpot.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gpg-zip.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gpgsplit.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/gpg.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/gnupg.7.gz
```

если есть соответствующий файл в каталогах `/usr/share/man/ru/*/` (`ru` — это и есть «на русском»), то и *man*-страницу «по-русски» можно посмотреть.

согласно `man man` (*man*-страница о самой программе `man`), по умолчанию на выбор языка влияет значение переменных окружения `LANG`, `LC_MESSAGES` и других, имеющих отношение к локали. (насколько мне известно, список, в порядке приоритета от большего к меньшему — `LC_ALL, LANG, LC_MESSAGES, LANGUAGE`).

собственно, если у вас правильно настроены эти переменные для отображения русского языка в интерфейсе (посмотреть их все «разом» можно командой `locale`), то и *man*-страницы будут отображаться (при наличии) — русскоязычные.

если по каким-то причинам вам не нужна перенастройка локали (или, хотя бы, переопределение какой-нибудь из перечисленных переменных), то вы можете вызвать программу `man` с опцией `-L язык`. например:

```
$ man -L ru man
```

---

на всякий случай приведу и примеры с переназначением переменных:

```
$ LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 man man
$ LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 man man
$ LC_MESSAGES=ru_RU.UTF-8 man man
$ LANGUAGE=ru man man
```

для `LANGUAGE` имеет смысл указывать именно так — только язык (`ru`), без территории (`RU`) и набора символов (`UTF-8`).

Comment: Я установил везде где можно русский, но `man grep` всё равно на английском. Есть ли способ скачать дополнительные man-страницы на русском? Например, вот тут https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=grep&category=1 я могу почитать man на русском, они существуют! Вопрос лишь в том, почему они лежат на этом сайте, а не в репозиториях моего дистрибутива? Я хотел бы иметь возможность изучать систему на родном языке нативно и без доступа в интернет.

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит ждать, что man на необхимом вам языке для интересующей вас страницы появится сразу же, как только вы проделаете все необходимые манипуляции по смене локали либо другим из вышеперечисленных способов.

Дело в том, что далеко не все страницы man переведены на другие языки, в том числе и на русский. Переводы сделаны лишь для малой части страниц. Наример, для такой классики, как `man grep`, перевода до сих пор нет.

Comment: *`"Например, для такой классики, как man grep, перевода до сих пор нет."`*.  Да, похоже это следствие национальных черт нашего характера